# Ways to inject Spatial Meta Data into video with Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, shared-libraries, 360-virtual-reality

I'm trying to inject Spacial meta data into 360 video so it runs on Youtube/Facebook etc - using video that is cut on a Java server with FFMPEG and will run on a Linux AWS EC2 Instance.

I've tried to use this library
https://github.com/pedroSG94/metadata-spherical-injector

Which is for Android and seems to wrap this .so library
https://github.com/pedroSG94/metadata-spherical-injector/tree/master/metadatavideo/src/main/libs/x86

with this script
https://github.com/pedroSG94/metadata-spherical-injector/blob/master/metadatavideo/src/main/java/com/pedro/metadatavideo/VideoInjector.java

I have no idea how to get this running on a Java server, or if it's possible. Can anyone let me know if this is going to work or if I need to find another way of injecting the meta data?

Can FFMPEG do it?

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on FFMPEG and used Exiftools. This works really well.